# JSON - Data Manipulation in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm new to working with python and even newer to working with JSON and I'm having some trouble getting some JSON Data into a format I can use. Please pardon my possible misuse of the correct JSON terminology here.

**Issue:**

I'm using [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/running-chapt.html) to pull in data from the "Key Statistics" page for a stock ([AAPL](https://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=AAPL) for example). The JSON that comes back is then put in a multilevel dictionary. There are essentially three unique ways the data is structured at the level I'd like to use.

1. Some data lines that come back simply have the data in them: `u'Beta': u'1.26'`
2. Other lines have a further level with a content key like this: `u'BookValuePerShare': {u'content': u'19.01', u'term': u'mrq'}`.
3. A few stat keys have multiple content keys available as well: `u'AvgVol': [{u'content': u'59,323,400', u'term': u'3 month'},  {u'content': u'49,103,900', u'term': u'10 day'}]`.

My end goal is to put these in a pandas data frame with the following structure for these 3 types:

1. For the lines simply with the data, they'll remain the same
2. For lines with a 'content' key, the 'content' should be the value of the variable. Additionally, I'd like to add the 'term' to the variable name. For example, `BookValuePerShare` above would have the end result of (comma separation mine):
    `BookValuePerShare-mrq, 19.01`
3. For the unique stats with multiple pieces of 'content', create a new row for each unique 'term' of that content. For example, AvgVol would turn into two rows (comma separation mine):

   ```
   AvgVol-3 month,59323400
   AvgVol-10 day,49103900
   ```

Below is my current code that puts it into a dictionary. I just don't even know where to start after this.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd

# build query and get into dictionary
full_query = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.keystats%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'AAPL'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2F    datatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"
r = urlopen(full_query).read().decode('UTF-8')
data = json.loads(r)

# view data
data['query']['results']['stats']

# chuck into data frame in current state
# issue with 'content' keys
df = pd.DataFrame(data['query']['results'])
```

Thanks for helping an amateur!

Comment: There are plenty of Python interfaces to the Yahoo API already: `matplotlib.finance.yahoo_quotes_historical_yahoo`, or `ystockquote`, for instance.

Comment: @katrielalex Thanks, I'll look into those, though from a brief look I'm not sure they capture all the information I'm looking for.

Comment: @pmbaumga you're likely going to struggle getting a good answer here as your question reads like, "somebody solve my business problem." You'll likely get better answers if you can identify the single coding issue that you're hung on and ask about that.

Comment: in addition you're loading a library to get `urlopen` but that's not imported in your code

Comment: I tried to open the URL from your example using a browser and I get `{
error: {
lang: "en-US",
description: "No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.keystats"
}
}`